# Laravel Sanctum returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-sanctum

**Context:**

I need to create a page in my website that is a SPA, basically its a voting page that a user inserts its social number, and when the start button is clicked, I need to Login a user I've created for the voting,  using Sanctum, and get the token for the next Ajax requests.

**Problems:**

1. I cannot authenticate the user using Auth:: because it must not be able to access the website, only this single page, how can I get the user in the controller? it comes with the request?
2. I make a request to a function that validates the social number input and then create a token for the voting user and return in the request and save it, but when I make another request and send in the token in the Authorisation header, it always give me the 401 Unauthorized error.

**Validate social number and return token function:**

```
 public function verifyNIF(Request $request){
    $nif = $request->nif;
    $slug = $request->slug;

    //TODO:validates NIF in DB

    $user = CbsHelpers::getInPersonUser();


    $token = $user->createToken('in-person-token')->plainTextToken;


    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'token' => $token,
    ]);



}
```

**Ajax request with token in Authorisation header (returns 401 Unauthorized)**

```
 function voteInPerson(topic){
    let topicId = topic.data('topic-id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/vote",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+token
        },
        data: {

            slug: slug,
            topicId: topicId,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === "no available votes" && topic.hasClass("not-voted")) {
                showWarningModal(data);
            }
            else {
              changeTopicVote(topic, data);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            if (data.status === 401)
                showWarningModal("login needed");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the route was set to middleware('auth') instead of 'auth:sanctum'